# Maintain aspect ratio on browser window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have a simple page with images, and when the user clicks the image, it opens up a new browser window with the image filling the area. I have the css set on the new window so that the image height and width are both 100% (and `overflow` is set to `hidden`) so that the window can be resized.

But what I need is for the window to maintain aspect ratio if the user resizes it. Right now, I'm stuck because I'm not getting how the event works, but I think I'm making this harder than it needs to be. Right now I have:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var height = $(this).attr("innerHeight");
        var width = $(this).attr("innerWidth");
        if(height/width != .75){
            window.resizeTo(width,width*.75);
        }
    });
});
```

Before I added the conditional, the window would immediately start shrinking (apparently opening a new window fires the resize event). Adding the conditional preventing this from happening when the window opens, but any resizing starts the shrinking again.

Is it just because the height and width are never exactly the right ratio (should I manually set the width to a round number ever time) or is there something else I'm doing wrong? Or is there some other way to get what I'm after that's more straightforward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're on the right track, but `resizeTo()` resizes the *entire* browser window, including window frames, toolbars, menus, etc.

So, when you call `resizeTo()`, it fires, detects the *inner* height/width isn't the desired aspect ratio, and resizes the entire window, frames and toolbars and all.

This then fires `resizeTo()` again, which finds, again, the inner aspect ratio isn't right, and so keeps firing and resizing *ad infinitum*.

To fix this, you'd need to:

1. *Detect* the outer size by resizing and then testing the innerWidth/innerHeight. Remember, this can change as the user works with their browser.
2. Call `resizeTo` with a size that accounts for the outer chrome and achieves the desired aspect ratio for the innerWidth/inner Height.

Comment: I think you called it, but I'm still having screwy issues. It keeps "wobbling" between sizes, like the bottom will grow and shrink. I seem to have this problem less when I set the outer adjustment manually (meaning I set the outer width difference to 10, for example). It just seems like this has to have been worked out already.

Comment: Could be a rounding issue. I.e., you set the height with width * 0.75, but when it resizes, the resize event fires again, and the height is not *exactly* 0.75 x width because of rounding. Try rounding up (using Math.Ceiling) both the test and the resizeTo() call.

Comment: Still not working, but you were right about the outside/inside issue with the panels, etc.